# How to get redirect string parameter using OAuth 2.0?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am writing small utility for linux. So how can i get redirect url value?

Quote from Google Docs:

> If the user has not yet granted access, the authorization server asks them to grant your application access. If they grant access, they get redirected to `redirect_uri` with a `code` query string parameter.

Comment: you have to register your app and configure that in https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: @Victor.Palyvoda, I have two redirects: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob and localhost. I can set redirect to special porn on my localhost. By how can i handle this redirect?

Comment: here is explanation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: @Victor.Palyvoda, I don't know how to get this redirect URL. I have authentication URL `auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()`. How can I get redirect URL of it's paremeters?